# What is the Elderseal level of a Kinsect?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

Every dragon-element weapon has an **[Elderseal level](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/325834/what-is-elderseal)**, the strength of weakening an elder dragon's power.

Well, except kinsects. Even Switch Axes' Dragon Phial has an Elderseal level, but I have yet to see a kinsect's Elderseal level.

**How strong are they?** Do Kinsects have low, medium or high Elderseal level? Or not? Or do they depend on a kinsect lineage?

Answer (score 1):

With an addon called [HunterPie](https://www.nexusmods.com/monsterhunterworld/mods/2645) (PC only, **use at your own risk**), you can actually see the Elderseal 'value' (like an ailment value e.g., paralysis value) of a monster.

Striking a Dragon element Kinsect yielded 2~3 Elderseal, which was the same value as striking with [Alatreon Star](https://monsterhunterworld.wiki.fextralife.com/Alatreon+Star), which has a low Elderseal. Striking with weapons with higher Elderseal levels yielded higher Elderseal values. Also, this value did not change as I change the weapon. Thus, we can safely assume Kinsects' Elderseal plays at the same level as low Elderseal weapons.